# Return data where data doesn't exist

Tags: sql, sql-server-express, business-intelligence

Have been designing SQL reports for a week. Please be gentle.

I am designing a report for use in an application we use. I want to return a list of all employees & all time they've spent working. If an Employee has recorded no time I still want them to show but with 0.00 or No Time. I can design & preview the report in SQL designer & it works.

When it comes to adding the WHERE conditions/Macros & loading it into the application it doesn't show employees who haven't recorded any time.

The following is my most successful attempt at getting the WHERE clause right. However, if I run the report on a week where nobody has recorded any time, it will only return about 1/3 of the employees & I can't figure out why!

```
SELECT CAST(1 AS bit) AS IsTimeEntry
     , Employees.Name
     , TimeEntries.EntryDateTime
     , TimeEntries.Duration / 60 AS Duration
FROM Employees 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TimeEntries ON TimeEntries.Employee = Employees.ID
WHERE 
   (TimeEntries.EntryDateTime BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate) 
   OR TimeEntries.Duration =0 
   OR TimeEntries.Duration IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change WHERE into AND

```
SELECT        CAST(1 AS bit) AS IsTimeEntry, Employees.Name, 
TimeEntries.EntryDateTime, TimeEntries.Duration / 60 AS Duration
FROM Employees LEFT OUTER JOIN
     TimeEntries ON TimeEntries.Employee = Employees.ID
AND ((TimeEntries.EntryDateTime BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate) 
 OR TimeEntries.Duration =0 OR TimeEntries.Duration IS NULL)
```

Comment: Absolute legend. Worked like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for your query failing is that you put part of the join criteria in your WHERE clause instead of the ON clause.

What happens is this: You find employee A (who has timeentries, but not in the time range given). You find entries in timeentries for employee A, so you join them. Then in your WHERE clause you notice that all matches found are on other time ranges, so you remove them all. No employee A record remains in your result set.

What you want to happen is: Find employee A. Find all his timeentries in the given range. If you find none, then outer-join a NULL record so you keep this employee in your result set.

```
select
  cast(1 as bit) as istimeentry, 
  e.name, 
  t.entrydatetime, 
  t.duration / 60 as duration
from employees e
left outer join timeentries t
  on t.employee = e.id and t.entrydatetime between @fromdate and @todate;
```

Comment: Fantastic. I will have a good play around with this. Thank you